# replace range values to one value SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I didn't found a right topic of this question so hopefully someone can help me. I want to replace a value into my phpmyadmin database by the next code:

```
update IGNORE `v3j8z_virtuemart_products`
set `product_in_stock` = replace(`product_in_stock`, BETWEEN '1000' AND '1000000', '1000000')
```

This code works when i use a replacement of one value to another but now i want to change the range between 1000 and 1000000 it doesn't. I'm wondering about what causes the error in this code?

Thanks in advance.

Jarik

Comment: I have never seen `replace()` with a `between` statement.  The documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) says nothing about it.  Does this query really work?

Comment: Can you share the code that works? What is the data type of `product_in_stock`?

Comment: Are you really doing a string replacement, and you want to replace any string `1000`, `1001`, ... `99999` with the string `100000`, or are you merely wanting to set `product_in_stock` to `100000` where it's less than `100000`? What is the data type for `product_in_stock`?

Comment: Marcus Adams is right, but I suspect that the original question was just using quoted values incorrectly. To the OP: If that column is supposed to be a number that you do math with, make it a numeric type! It will save you many, many hours of work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you mean, but I think what you want to do is this:

```
update v3j8z_virtuemart_products
 set product_in_stock = 1000000
 where product_in_stock BETWEEN 1000 AND 1000000;
```

This will update all records with a product_in_stock value between 1000 and 1000000 with a new value of 1000000.

Comment: A couple of things: You probably don't want to IGNORE errors in the update. Also, those backticks aren't needed for StackOverflow when you're already indenting to show code. Finally, and this is actually pretty important to the answer, if the `product_in_stock` column is a string, then those numeric comparisons will yield results you may not expect.

I'm applying those changes to your answer.

Comment: But also, to the one posting this answer: Yes, I think you understood the question, and your answer will solve the problem.